# Split rows by day and hour and sum up the utilized duration in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have been given an input dataframe as:

```
Resource Id Resource    Scheduled   Allocated   Utilized    Start Time  End Time
0   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   0   0   2021-11-01 00:00:00 2021-11-01 06:00:00
1   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   1   1   2021-11-01 06:00:00 2021-11-01 06:22:00
2   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   0   0   2021-11-01 06:22:00 2021-11-01 07:45:00
3   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   1   1   2021-11-01 07:45:00 2021-11-01 07:54:00
4   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   0   0   2021-11-01 07:54:00 2021-11-01 07:55:00
5   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   1   1   2021-11-01 07:55:00 2021-11-01 07:55:00
6   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   0   0   2021-11-01 07:55:00 2021-11-01 08:15:00
7   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   1   1   2021-11-01 08:15:00 2021-11-01 08:15:00
8   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   0   0   2021-11-01 08:15:00 2021-11-01 08:15:00
9   AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   1   1   2021-11-01 08:15:00 2021-11-01 08:16:00
10  AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   0   0   2021-11-01 08:16:00 2021-11-01 08:18:00
11  AmbientPacking1 AmbientPacking1 1   1   1   2021-11-01 08:18:00 2021-11-01 08:18:00

start_Date = min(Start Time.dt.date)
end_Date = max(End Time.dt.date)
```

I want to modify this dataframe into hourly between the start_Date and end_Date and add up the duration for each hour. If "Utilized" is '1', then add those minutes together and if "Utilized" is '0' then add the minutes for that hour.

Output DataFrame is as below :

[image]

Here, from the input dataframe, you can see the Start Time is 1/11/2021 0:00 and End time is 1/11/2021 6:00. So from midnight till 6 am the resource ID is not utilized '0'. Therefore the first 6 rows in output dataframe is :
[image]

Similarly in 2nd row of i/p dataframe the resource ID is utilized('1') between 6:00:00am and 6:22:00am.So, the utilized minutes are 22mins and not utilized are 60-22 = 38mins. The output row is :
[image]

For the time interval 7:00 - 8:00, the sum of Not Utilized(0) time is 51 mins and Utilized(1) is 9 mins, the output row is:

[image]

Same has to be repeated for other rows and resource ID. This is a very vague client request and I cant refuse it. I tried creating a dataframe with resource ID, Resource, Date, Hour and Time Interval as shown below. But I was confused how to fill the Scheduled, allocated and Utilized column based on the hour range/time interval and then calculate the "Duration(min)" column. I think my approach is not correct. If I could be guided how to complete this task it would be very helpful. I dont think it will be an issue if we can add other columns in the output dataframe to make data more understandable.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: please don't use images of data, provide a [reproducible example](/q/20109391/16343464) as text or DataFrame constructor

Comment: read following link : **Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: I think it's okay to have images for understanding, but **input** for run must always exist **in text**.

Comment: @mozway, I have provided the dataframe as text now. I am trying to copy the dataframe from csv and paste it in question but it asks me to paste as image.

Comment: @Amit thanks, is the start time always identical to the previous end time?

Comment: @mozway, Yes, so far in the sample dataset I have, it has time in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can replicate the rows with [`Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html), then split the cumulated time:

```
step = 60

out = (df
       .assign(date=lambda d: d['Start Time'].dt.date,
               total=lambda d: d['End Time'].sub(df['Start Time']).dt.total_seconds().div(step)
              )
       .loc[lambda d: d.index.repeat(np.ceil(d['total'].div(step)))]
       .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount(),
               start=lambda d: d['Start Time'].dt.floor(f'{step}min').add(pd.to_timedelta(d['n']*step, unit='min')),#.dt.time,
               end=lambda d: d['start'].add(pd.Timedelta('60min')).dt.time,
               duration=lambda d: d['total'].mask(d['n'].add(1).mul(step).le(d['total']), 60),
              )
       .assign(start=lambda d: d['start'].dt.time)
       .drop(columns=['Start Time', 'End Time', 'total', 'n'])
      )
```

Output:

```
        Resource Id         Resource  Scheduled  Allocated  Utilized        date     start       end  duration
0   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  00:00:00  01:00:00      60.0
0   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  01:00:00  02:00:00      60.0
0   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  02:00:00  03:00:00      60.0
0   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  03:00:00  04:00:00      60.0
0   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  04:00:00  05:00:00      60.0
0   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  05:00:00  06:00:00      60.0
1   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          1         1  2021-11-01  06:00:00  07:00:00      22.0
2   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  06:00:00  07:00:00      60.0
2   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  07:00:00  08:00:00      83.0
3   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          1         1  2021-11-01  07:00:00  08:00:00       9.0
4   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  07:00:00  08:00:00       1.0
6   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  07:00:00  08:00:00      20.0
9   AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          1         1  2021-11-01  08:00:00  09:00:00       1.0
10  AmbientPacking1  AmbientPacking1          1          0         0  2021-11-01  08:00:00  09:00:00       2.0
```

Comment: for 6:00-7:00 time interval the sum of utilized and not utilized should be 60 mins. here for not utilized it should be 38 not 60 and same for 7:00-8:00 interval, it should be total 60 mins with utilized(1) = 9 and utilized(0)=51mins. Can you please modify the code?

Comment: @jezrael, can you please help here.